# + Symbol in Regular Expression PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to use preg_match and regular expression in PHP to check that a string starts with either "+44" or "0", but how can I do this without the + being read as matching the preceding character once or more? Would (+44|0) work?

Comment: Use a backslash to escape. `(\+44|0)`

Comment: Double backslash, actually. PHP itself doesn't know know regular expression semantics, so you have to pass it as a string, where the regular expression's backslash needs to be escaped again.

Comment: [**Related ...**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it several ways. Amongst those I know two:

One is escaping the `+` with escape character(i.e. back slash)

```
^(\+44|0)
```

Or placing the `+` inside the character class `[]` where it means the character as it's literal meaning.

```
^([+]44|0)
```

`^` is the anchor character that means the start of the string/line based on your flag(modifier).

Answer (score 4):

use the ^ to signify start with and a backslash \ to escape the + character. So you'll check for

```
^\+44 | ^0
```

In php, to store the regexp in a string, you don't need to double backslash \ to confuse things, just use single quotes instead like:

```
$regexp = '^\+44 | ^0';
```

In fact, you don't even need to use anything, this works too:

```
$regexp = "^\+44 | ^0";
```

Comment: As I will be adding more to the pattern, and am worried that it won't separate it unless there are brackets, I decided to go with the \\ method, but thank you for teaching me this too :)

Answer (score 3):

The backslash is the default escape character for regular expressions. You may have to escape the backslash itself as well if it is used in a PHP string, so you'd use something like `"(\\+44|0)"` as string constant. The regular expression itself would then be `(\+44|0)`.